# Using a x:Static with MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

How can I use `x:Static` with a multi binding as below?

```
 <TextBlock.Text>
       <MultiBinding StringFormat="{x:Static language:Resource.Message} : {0}">
                  <Binding Path="NoOfMessages" />
      </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

There is an error yelling at me with this code.

Comment: Do not confuse `x:Static` with `StaticResource`.

Comment: If he is referring to a string resource in a RESX file (and it looks like he is), then `x:Static` is the proper thing to use in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use multiple inlines:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run Text="{x:Static language:Resource.Message}"/>
   <Run Text=":"/>
   <Run Text="{Binding NoOfMessages, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative if you want to rely on `MultiBinding` and `StringFormat`:

```
<TextBlock.Text>
   <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} : {1}">
      <Binding Source="{x:Static language:Resource.Message}"/>
      <Binding Path="NoOfMessages" />
   </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Make sure to use the [escape sequence `{}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/escape-sequence-markup-extension) for the braces.